# how to pass array as parameter in restler 3.0

Tags: curl, cygwin, restler

I am new to restler3.0. I am trying to run sample examples given in the public folder. I got strucked when trying to run the routing example. I am trying to call the api/method/{param1}, in this method one more param is there and that is in array format. I dont know how to pass array values to this param2. I tried some of the ways but all has been failed. Someone can explain me regarding how to pass array to this method. I am using cygwin terminal to execute curl commands

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this one (or similar):

```
 * Auto routed method which maps to POST api/method/{param1}
 *
 * @param int       $param1 map to url
 * @param array     $param2 map to request body
 * @param string    $param3 map to query string
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function postMethod($param1, array $param2, $param3 = 'optional')
 {
    return 'you have called Api::postMethod()';
 }
```

then $param2 maps to the request body. So if you are POSTing, $param2 would be the array of POST variables you are submitting.

I'm not familiar with curl via cygwin terminal, but I *think* it would be something like this?

```
curl -X POST http://myserver/api/method/1 -d firstname=Joe -d lastname=Smith
```

which would send `1` into $param1 and `firstname=Joe&lastname=Smith` into $param2.